Align and Snap a CAD-Modeled Connector to the End of an Extruded Profile Curve with Matching Orientation Using Geometry Nodes
I'm trying to connect an object to the end of an extruded curve in Blender, ensuring that they align correctly and maintain the same orientation. I want this setup to be managed through Geometry Nodes, so that any changes to the main curve are automatically reflected in the final design.
The object I want to connect is a special connector that I have modeled in CAD software (Onshape) because its exact dimensions and shape are crucial:

My goal is to attach this connector to the end of my extruded curve, as shown below. This curve also maintains the same profile shape as connector's bottom profile:

I would like the final result to look like the image below, which I achieved manually (the extruded curve path has been solidified and holes should match as well):

I have tried several approaches found online, but none have worked for me. You can see some of my attempts in the attached file. The main issues I'm facing are aligning the connector properly, maintaining its exact orientation, and snapping it correctly to the extruded profile. Additionally, when I tilt the end of the curve, the connector doesn't rotate at all, and I’m not sure how to fix this.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help.


Maybe related/duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/289747/align-object-instance-to-point-away-from-end-of-curve/289752 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286437/extruding-a-filled-face-with-a-hole-in-it-along-a-curve-using-geometry-nodes

@quellenform Thanks, I have already checked and tested those, the first one is already implemented in my file, it does not align or snap correctly and does not take into account tilt rotation. The second one is not related, it is something I have already achieved with the extruded profile.

Seeing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285920/how-to-use-a-tilt-to-rotate-object-following-a-curve , I was able to solve the issue

The second question may not be relevant, but the answer it contains is. In both answers I give for both questions, I use the node Curve to Points, which automatically provides the rotation of the respective point at the end. This is usually easier and more reliable than two Align Euler to Vector in a row. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/289752/145249

IMHO this also answers this question at least my answer there: Rounded cap on Curve with Geo Nodes

I managed to solve the problem (based on the link I sent in the comment section). The key step was:

Align Euler to Vector Nodes: I used two of these nodes. The first aligns the connector to the curve's tangent, ensuring it follows the curve’s direction. The second aligns the connector to the curve's tilt, ensuring it matches the curve’s orientation.

By correctly using the curve's tangent and tilt information, the connector dynamically follows any changes to the curve.
Here’s the node setup I used:

